# Getting a java.lang.RuntimeException: Unmarshalling unknown type code in Activity onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` in which I've implemented `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` properly to maintain `Activity` state. If I rotate the device, everything happens successfully and `Activity` state is maintained.

The problem occurs when I put the app in background and kill it with a Task Killer OR Turn on the "Don't keep Activities" options in the Developer Options of the device. In this case, when I relaunch the `Activity`, I get the following Exception

```
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vss.example/com.vss.example.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b389dec8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6619245 at offset 800
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b389dec8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6619245 at offset 800
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2032)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1687)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2022)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1232)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1605)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:928)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:900)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1130)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
09-05 16:04:36.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1976):     ... 11 more
```

I'm aware that this happens when we try to read from the parcel in the wrong order that we wrote it, but if that's the case, shouldn't the `Exception` occur whenever we rotate the device as well? I believe it follows the exact same process, but I'm not a 100% sure after today.

Incidentally, this happens only in an `Activity` where I've added a custom `View`. The implementation is identical to that of the `FragmentTabHost` in the support library(I copied and modified that source code, actually), except for a few changes I've made. But the changes don't affect the previous code for `FragmentTabHost` State. Here are the relevant code snippets -

```
static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {

    String curTab;

    SavedState(final Parcelable superState) {

        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(final Parcel in) {

        super(in);
        curTab = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {

        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeString(curTab);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "SavedStateFragmentTabHost.SavedState{"
                + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                + " curTab=" + curTab + "}";
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> SAVED_STATE_CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {

        @Override
        public SavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {

            return new SavedState(
                    in);
        }

        @Override
        public SavedState[] newArray(final int size) {

            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {

    final Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    final SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
    ss.curTab = getCurrentTabTag();
    return ss;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state) {

    final SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    setCurrentTabByTag(ss.curTab);
}
```

If I comment out the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods in my custom `FragmentTabHost`, the `Exception` doesn't occur. Has anybody else faced this issue before? Could you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have to rename `SAVED_STATE_CREATOR` into `CREATOR` to get it working. The name of this static field is a part of [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)'s contract.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it! The field was named CREATOR earlier, but I went through the commit logs and found out someone from the team had changed the name for some reason!

Comment: I don't see why Android doesn't throw a warning there, however.. "Parcellable must include a public static field named "CREATOR"'.. :/

Comment: This is because one of super classes has the correct field. Otherwise there would be an exception.